# Tailor in Hurghada, Egypt

Tags: clothing, egypt, services

I'm trying to locate a tailor (khayat) in Hurghada who can make men's traditional pants fast and cheap. I will wear these wide and full pants "sirwal" under galabeya (with crotch almost down to the ground).

Model: http://world4.eu/egypt-costumes-port-said/

Comment: If we entertained a question from Mark Mayo on this topic, we can entertain a question from a noob also. Accordingly, please do not vote to close, thanks.

Comment: @pnuts, yowzah that's it, nice searching.

Comment: @GayotFow Sorry, but voting to close one question does not oblige people to go find every other question that they also think should be closed.